# ReactJS/D3.JS How to add extensions to D3 in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, components, prototype

Does somebody have an idea about how to port this very useful prototype
to ReactJS Component (actually to PureComponent)

If I place it inside the constructor or the component body it returns an error. I'm using a standard D3 npm package initialized by "import * as d3 from 'd3'"

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function () {

return this.each(function () {
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
});

};
```

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Good news - the functionality you are looking for is already available in D3 as of v4.

Check out `selection.raise()`: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.0/README.md#selection_raise

Hope this helps!